# Json object is getting created in a seperate tag for jolt transformation

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying below to convert from single object to array but it is creating in seperate tag. Tried with multiple combinations but not getting in same tag

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "settings": [
      {
        "account": [
          {
            "number": "1",
            "purpose": {
              "type": "netflix"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my jolt spec is as below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "settings": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.&2.[&1].&",
            "account": {
              "*": {
                "*": "&5.&4.[&3].&2.[&1].&",
                "purpose": {
                  "0": {
                    "@(2,purpose)": "&4.[&3].&2"
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "@(2,purpose)": "&4.[&3].&2[]"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output coming as this

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "settings": [
      {
        "account": [
          {
            "number": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "account": [
    {
      "purpose": [
        {
          "type": "netflix"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

where as expected output should be like below

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "settings": [
      {
        "account": [
          {
            "number": "1",
            "purpose": [
              {
                "type": "netflix"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can please let me know what is the wrong I am doing in the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add square brackets (`[]`) to the inner most object within the common nested curly braces of an object in a shift transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "settings": {
          "*": {
            "account": {
              "*": {
                "*": "&5.&4[&3].&2[&1].&", // the elements other than "purpose"
                "purpose": {
                  "@": "&6.&5[&4].&3[&2].&1[]" // +1 level deeper than the other elements
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Edit : If you need to return the same expected output for both type of inputs in which the purpose is a key of an object ( `"purpose": { "type": "netflix" }`  ) as already exists within the original input or that is a key of an array of an object ( `"purpose": [{ "type": "netflix" }]`  ) as stated in the latest comment, then you might use the following spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "settings": {
          "*": {
            "account": {
              "*": {
                "*": "&5.&4[&3].&2[&1].&",
                "purpose": {
                  "*": {
                    "@1": "&7.&6[&5].&4[&3].&2[]" //this will return whenever "purpose" is an object only
                  },
                  "0": {
                    "@1": "&7.&6[&5].&4[&3].&2" //this will return whenever "purpose" has 
                                                //an array wrapper which nests the object inside
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Btw, you should fix the question so as to include that extra criteria as well.

Comment: hi but if with this if purpose is already array its giving dobule [[]], "purpose": [{
              "type": "netflix"
            }] then output coming as "purpose" : [ [ {
          "type" : "netflix"
        } ] ]

Comment: yes the spec you have suggest works when the purpose come as "purpose": {
              "type": "netflix"
            } this correct, but my problem was some time it comes as "purpose": [{
              "type": "netflix"
            }] this too, so I was tring for single spec which can work for both scenarios, in that case this spec given me doble times[[]] @Barbaros Özhan